# Can't seem to add style to header / div when scrolled to top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

This is really odd, because I've used this script before on other projects, and it's worked. But I'm stumped why it's not functioning now.

Basically, what I want is for the header section of my page to stick to the top of the page once that section gets to the top of the page. Instead, the script gets completely ignored and never adds the div, which in turn triggers the styles in my CSS to stick that div to the top.

Page in question: http://new.cajunland.com/

Script:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function($){
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 1){  
jQuery('header').addClass("stick");
    } else {
jQuery('header').removeClass("stick");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
body, html {
  overflow: auto!important;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

To this:

```
body, html {
  overflow: initial;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That made all the difference.